# SQL table to include 0 value rows as well

Tags: sql

I have a couple of tables, tblUser and tblTableUsage that keeps track of who has saved data on what table/class.

```
tblUser: UserID, UserName, Department
tblTableUsage: UserID, ClassName, DateUsed


DECLARE @ThisDate DATETIME
SET @ThisDate = '2018-03-05 00:00:00.000'

SELECT 
  DISTINCT(tu.ClassName)
FROM [tblTableUsage] tu
INNER JOIN tblUser u on tu.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
WHERE DATEADD(Day,0,datediff(day, 0, tu.SaveDate)) = @ThisDate
AND u.Department = 'DD'
GROUP BY tu.ClassName, DATEADD(DAY, 0, datediff(Day, 0, tu.SaveDate))
ORDER BY ClassName
```

This gives me a unique list of all the ClassName items used by the 'DD' department for '3/5/2018'

```
SELECT 
  u.UserName,  
  tu.ClassName, 
  COUNT(tu.[UserID]) as 'Items Worked On',  
  DATEADD(DAY, 0, datediff(Day, 0, tu.SaveDate)) as 'Date'
FROM [tblTableUsage] tu
INNER JOIN [tblUsers] u on tu.[UserID] = u.UserID
WHERE DATEADD(Day,0,datediff(day, 0, tu.SaveDate)) = @ThisDate and u.Department = 'DD'
GROUP BY UserName,  tu.ClassName, DATEADD(DAY, 0, datediff(Day, 0, tu.SaveDate))
ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY, 0, datediff(Day, 0, tu.SaveDate)),ClassName, u.UserName
```

This gives me all the Users, the Classes used, and how many times.  However I have ClassName entries where only 1 user has used it.

```
USERNAME        CLASSNAME       ITEMS WORKED ON         DATE
User A                   CLASS 1                 3                              3/5/2018
User B                   CLASS 1                 12                           3/5/2018
User C                   CLASS 2                 12                           3/5/2018
User A                   CLASS 3                 2                              3/5/2018
User B                   CLASS 3                 12                           3/5/2018
User C                   CLASS 3                 3                              3/5/2018
```

What I want to see is the entries where the Items Worked On = 0 as well.

```
User A                   CLASS 1                 3                              3/5/2018
User B                   CLASS 1                 12                           3/5/2018
User C                   CLASS 1                 0                              3/5/2018                              <--THIS ONE
User A                   CLASS 2                 0                              3/5/2018                              <--THIS ONE
User B                   CLASS 2                 0                              3/5/2018                              <--THIS ONE
User C                   CLASS 2                 12                           3/5/2018
User A                   CLASS 3                 2                              3/5/2018
User B                   CLASS 3                 12                           3/5/2018
User C                   CLASS 3                 3                              3/5/2018
```

Any thoughts on how to get this? Thanks!

I'm looking to build a report based on this data and it's a lot easier if the 0 data row entries are present so I don't have to add them manually...

Comment: tag your database please

Comment: add this in query and check `isnull(classname,0)` and also in group by  or could write a case statement

Comment: Which dbms???  The syntax is different for different dbms.

Comment: Sorry. I renamed the tables for security purposes and may have mislabeled some.

Answer (score 1):

Generate all the users and classes with a `cross join`, then join in and aggregate:

```
SELECT u.UserName, c.ClassName, 
       COUNT(tu.[UserID]) as items_worked_on  
       CAST(tu.SaveDate as Date) as dte
FROM (SELECT u.*
      FROM tblusers u
      WHERE  u.Department = 'DD'
     ) u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT tu.ClassName 
      FROM tblTableUsage tu
      WHERE CAST(tu.SaveDate as DATE) = @ThisDate
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     tblTableUsage tu
     ON CAST(tu.SaveDate as DATE) = @ThisDate AND tu.UserId = u.UserId and
        tu.ClassName = c.ClassName
INNER JOIN [tblUsers] u on tu.[UserID] = u.UserID
WHERE DATEADD(Day,0,datediff(day, 0, tu.SaveDate)) = @ThisDate and u.Department = 'DD'
GROUP BY u.UserName, cu.ClassName, CAST(tu.SaveDate as Date)
ORDER BY dte, ClassName, u.UserName;
```

Comment: I couldn't put my modifications under yours so I added it as a different solution but you are the man.

Answer (score 0):

declare @ThisDate datetime

Set @ThisDate = '2018-03-05 00:00:00.000'

SELECT tmpU.UserName, tmpTU.ClassName, ISNULL(COUNT(tu.ClassName),0) as 'Items Worked On'

FROM

(

```
            SELECT u.UserName, u.Department , u.UserID

            FROM tblUsers u

            WHERE  u.Department = 'Due Diligence'
```

) tmpU

CROSS JOIN

(

```
            SELECT DISTINCT tu.ClassName

            FROM tblTableUsage tu

            WHERE CAST(tu.SaveDate as DATE) = @ThisDate

            AND tu.[User] IN

            (

                            SELECT u.UserID

                            FROM tblUsers u

                            WHERE u.Department = 'Due Diligence'

            )
```

) tmpTU

LEFT JOIN tblTableUsage  tu ON DATEADD(Day,0,datediff(day, 0, tu.SaveDate)) = @ThisDate AND tu.[User] = tmpU.UserId and tu.ClassName = tmpTU.ClassName

GROUP BY tmpU.UserName, tmpTU.ClassName

ORDER BY tmpTU.ClassName, tmpU.UserName